# Symsquare Number 02

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

Symsquare4: The answer is a square grid which has the same words vertically and horizontally. The clue is a single sentence written in cryptic style and includes one anagram, one hidden word, one Charade and one Double Meaning, all as syntactically separate units. A rank indicator will indicate which word the anagram is:

> Third escape of a famous sprinter with a messed up sole (but a 10 with energy) that no Boer could hold.

Comment: Why is the word rot13(guveq) there (and why was rot13(oebamr) in your last one)?

Comment: A rank indicator will indicate which word the anagram is.  As I look at it this I see that this part of the explanation could be clearer:  A rank indicator will indicate which word in the grid is the anagram

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution

> ```
>  B O L T
>  O B O E
>  L O S E
>  T E E N
> ```

Double meaning

> *"escape of a famous sprinter"*
>  **BOLT** - double meaning "escape" and "famous sprinter"

Anagram

> *"messed up sole"*
>  **LOSE** - anagram of "sole"

Charade

> *"a 10 with energy"*
>  **TEEN** - TEN with E (energy) inside is the charade.

Hidden word

> *"no Boer could hold."*
>  **OBOE** - hidden word in nO BOEr

Comment: Is there a way to hide the individual components of the question that are being explained? Slicing up the question is part of the process and is a bit spoilery?

Comment: @ClaudeGoeminne That's a good point. I've edited the answer now to hide the individual components. Will do the same for the other.